# What does this sudo -l output mean and can this be priv. escalated?

Tags: linux, privilege-escalation, sudo

I am trying to do priviledge escalation of a linux box. 
My `sudo -l` output shows the following :

```
www-data@box:/scripts$ sudo -l
sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for www-data on box:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User www-data may run the following commands on box:
    (scriptmanager : scriptmanager) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

What does the (scriptmanager : scriptmanager) mean?

And in one of the directories that I listed, it showed :

```
www-data@box:/scripts$ ls -l
ls -l
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 scriptmanager scriptmanager  88 Feb  8 09:11 dek.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root          root            0 Feb  8 10:11 dik.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data      www-data      129 Feb  8 09:25 mmm.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 scriptmanager scriptmanager  58 Dec  4 17:03 test.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root          root           12 Feb  8 10:11 test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data      www-data       85 Feb  8 10:08 tmp.py
```

Is there a way to priviledge escalate to a root shell? I have limited user shell without the password.

Comment: For those considering answering: this is a HackTheBox challenge, so information that leads Sankalp in the right direction rather than gives them the exact answer on a plate would probably be best!

Comment: Thanks @Polynomial: Thats why I tried changing the names where the box name was listed.

Answer (score 3):

```
(scriptmanager : scriptmanager) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

means that you can run any command as *scriptmanager*, and optionally set your group to *scriptmanager* when doing so.
You won't need to provide a password when doing so.
The *scriptmanager* user (or group) may or may not have the privileges you ultimately want.

Comment: Ok so basically I can chown a file or a folder to scriptmanager, however, that does not mean that I can run any command as the scriptmanager right? For that I would have to do something like ```su scriptmanager``` right?

Comment: No, you can run any command as `scriptmanager` and do everything it can do.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for files or executables that *scriptmanager* owns already that you can modify.  Some of them may execute in a privileged context.

Answer (score 0):

You can run:

```
sudo -u scriptmanager <any command here>
```

Eg:

```
sudo -u scriptmanager /bin/bash
```

Comment: Can you explain what this command does? Just dumping a command without explanation is not very useful. And how would this escalate to `root`?